# Prove that $-\frac {x}{2}\leq f(x)-1\leq \frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x}{2}$ where $f(x)= \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $$\begin{cases}
f(x)= \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x},  & \text{if $x > 0$} \\
f(0)=1
\end{cases}$$

I have to prove that $\forall x \in \Bbb{R_+}-\frac {x}{2}\leq f(x)-1\leq \frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x}{2}$ so i can show that $f'_d(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$

I tried using the mean value inequality but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: If you look at the Taylor series for $e^{-x}$, when $x>0$ this is an alternating series, and so converges to a value between any two consecutive partial sums.  Now take the 2nd and 3rd partial sums and rearrange.

Comment: @Aaron this holds only for small $x$ (which may be enough for the OP) when the absolute values of summands are decreasing right from the start

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, of course, that was a silly oversight on my part. For any x, the terms will eventually be decreasing, but how far you need to go will depend on x. Although if the goal is simply to establish a limit using squeeze theorem, we don’t actually need the result to hold for all x.  I also think that we can use this argument for x<1 and crude bounds for x>1.

Comment: @Alex You have a few answers below. Any feedback from your side?

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen or used the Taylor Series before so I'm finding it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The given inequality is equivalent to: for $x>0$,
$$x\left(1-\frac {x}{2}\right)\leq 1-e^{-x}\leq x\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right),$$
that is
$$1-x\left(1+\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\leq e^{-x}\leq 1-x\left(1-\frac {x}{2}\right)$$
or
$$1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}\leq e^{-x}\leq 1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}.$$
Now, you may apply the [Lagrange's Remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) of the Taylor's expansion of $e^{-x}$ centered at $x_0=0$:  $\exists t,s\in (0,x)$ such that
$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{6}=
1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{s^4}{24}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

We know that Taylor series for $e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}...$ now $f(x)\approx \frac{1-(1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24})}{x}=\frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{24}}{x}=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^3}{24}$ thus $-\frac{x}{2}\leq f(x)-1\leq \frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ge0$, the given inequation is equivalent to

$$1-x+\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}\leq e^{-x}\leq1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}.$$

As equalities hold at $x=0$, you can differentiate and this is equivalent to

$$-1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq -e^{-x}\leq-1+x.$$

As equalities hold at $x=0$, you can differentiate and this is equivalent to

$$1-x\leq e^{-x}\leq1.$$

As equalities hold at $x=0$, you can differentiate and this is equivalent to

$$-1\leq-e^{-x}\leq0.$$

More generally, $e^{-x}$ is bracketed between successive Taylor approximations.

[image]